# How to include css files in Nextjs 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using nextjs 14 , and i want to know that how to include 'style.css' and other custom css files in nextjs project ?

My current file structure is

```
my-project/
├── components/
│   ├── footer.tsx
│   ├── header.tsx
│   └── page.tsx
├── pages/
│   ├── _app.tsx
│   └── index.tsx
├── styles/
│   ├── globals.css
│   └── styles.css
├── public/
│   └── image1.jpg
├── package.json
├── next.config.js
└── tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Next.js 14, including CSS files such as 'style.css' or other custom CSS files in your project is straightforward. Here's how you can do it:

1. **File Structure**: First, let's consider a common file structure in a Next.js project. You might have a structure like this:

   ```
   - components
   - pages
     - index.js
   - public
   - styles
     - style.css
   ```

   In this structure, your custom CSS file (`style.css`) is inside the `styles` directory.
2. **Including CSS in Your Component**: To use the CSS file in your Next.js components, you need to import it. For global styles like `style.css`, it's typical to import them into your `_app.js` file, which is the main entry point for all pages.

   If you don't have an `_app.js` file, you can create one inside the `pages` directory. Here's how it would look:

   ```js
   // pages/_app.js
   import '../styles/style.css';

   function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
     return <Component {...pageProps} />;
   }

   export default MyApp;
   ```

   This import statement tells Next.js to include your `style.css` file globally across all pages.
3. **Using CSS Modules**: For component-level styling, you might want to use CSS Modules, which are automatically supported by Next.js. To do this, name your CSS file in the format `[name].module.css`, for example, `Button.module.css`. You can import these styles directly into your components:

   ```js
   // components/Button.js
   import styles from './Button.module.css';

   function Button() {
     return <button className={styles.myButton}>Click me</button>;
   }
   ```

   In this example, `myButton` is a class defined in `Button.module.css`.
4. **Sass Support**: If you are using Sass (`.scss` or `.sass`), you can also import these files in a similar manner. Next.js supports Sass out of the box.
5. **Note on Public Directory**: Remember, the `public` directory is meant for static files like images, fonts, etc., and not for CSS files. CSS should be placed in a directory like `styles` as shown above.

Make sure to restart your Next.js server if it was running while you made these changes. This ensures that the new CSS files are properly included and compiled.

Comment: Thank you for reply , please tell me is my file structure is correct ? and also tell me is there '_app.js' file mandatory in nextjs 14 ? if yes then what is use of 'layout.tsx' ?

Comment: _app.js is part of the traditional pages router mode and is not strictly mandatory but often used for global settings. The layout.tsx file is more aligned with the new app router mode, offering a different approach to handling layouts and complex routing. Depending on your project requirements and the routing complexity, you can choose the appropriate mode and file structure.

Answer (score 1):

The import syntax would be as usual.

You can simply import using CSS file path.

`import 'path/to/styles.css';`

Comment: but in which file ? in which file should i import ? kindly explain

Comment: whichever component you need the styles to reflect

Comment: actually style.css and 'bootstrap.min.css' will use for every page so should i use in _app.js ? and _app.js file is mandatory in nextjs 14 ?

Comment: yes, you can import it on Layout.jsx or _app.js

Comment: Sir, can you please tell me difference between these files ? in which file should i put this code and reason behind this ?

Comment: These are two types of components that loads for each page. Both are same.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to add one CSS file to another CSS file like we import components in React.js.
You can add as many CSS files separately and they will work as expected.

Open your `_app.tsx` file in the `pages` directory. add this CSS files like this

```
import '../styles/globals.css'; // Import global styles
import '../styles/styles.css'; // Import additional custom styles
```

Comment: But i dont have '_app.tsx' file , Is this mandatory for nextjs 14 ?

Comment: in your current file structure I can see it bro. under pages.
it can be _app.js or _app.jsx something

Answer (score 0):

if you want organize your CSS into multiple files  ( **with tailwind** ) and combine them at build time by processing @import statements in advance, instead of in the browser.

The canonical plugin for handling this with PostCSS is postcss-import.

To use it, install the plugin via npm:

```
npm install -D postcss-import
```

Then add it as the very first plugin in your PostCSS configuration:

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

finally in global.css you can import your css file :

```
@import "./styles.css"
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```